# Implementing Google Game Services in Meteor Project

Tags: android, meteor, google-play-games

I want to make an android game that makes use of the Google Play Game services.  I'm planning on using the Meteor Framework to make it.

Is there a package for Meteor that allows you to make use of the Google Play Game Services API?  There must be something because the platform is available for webapps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing I found is a [node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-play-games-services).  You could then use meteorhacks:npm to use it.